# How to prove the rank of the following matrix >= n-1?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

The following was a Real symmetric matrix, it's size was nxn, how to prove the rank of A >= n-1?
all a's and b's non zero.

[image]

Comment: You have to know something about the a's and b's. For example if all the a's and b's are 0 then the rank is 0, while if all the a's are 1 and all the b's 0 the rank is n

Comment: Thanks, add all a's and b's are non zero.

Comment: You'd be better to go to a math site rather than a programming one. There is an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790896/tridiagonal-matrixs-rank-and-eigenvalues